# Sort equal but unordered data from two different excels

Tags: r, excel

I have these two excels with the same but unordered "ID's" attached to different "attendance" and "scores".

| ID | Attendance | Grades |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **359764** | **40** | **67** |
| **23546** | **60** | **65** |
| **124890** | **80** | **54** |

| ID | Attendance | Grades |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 235678 | 40 | 58 |
| 21324234 | 98 | 65 |
| **359764** | **55** | **70** |
| **23546** | **85** | **68** |
| **124890** | **90** | **65** |

I am looking for a way to take the unordered "ID's" and put them together in one, while transporting the "Attendance" and "Grades" in different columns, and then pass it to a new excel.

| ID | Attendance | Grades | Attendance | Grades |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 235678 |  |  | 40 | 58 |
| 21324234 |  |  | 98 | 65 |
| **359764** | **40** | **67** | **55** | **70** |
| **23546** | **60** | **65** | **85** | **68** |
| **124890** | **80** | **54** | **90** | **65** |

How could this be possible?

Comment: `dplyr::full_join()` is what you want.